# How do I turn off the border around Unity launcher icons?

Tags: unity, icons

Is there a way to turn off the boxes around the icons in Unity?

Clarification: I do **not** mean the backlight color -- there are plenty of questions about turning *that* off. I want the icons, and just the icons, to appear in the Unity bar, without any lights and shadows and borders. Can this be done?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The launcher icon overlays such as borders and highlights can be removed quite easily by changing 4 icon overlays in Unity.

1. Make a backup of the following image files in the folder
   `/usr/share/unity/4/`:

   ```
   launcher_icon_back_54.png
   launcher_icon_edge_54.png
   launcher_icon_glow_62.png
   launcher_icon_shine_54.png
   ```
2. Either make your own transparent images of the same size or download the files at

   ```
   wget -O transparent54.png "https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiFpK.png"
   wget -O transparent62.png "https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NvP0.png"
   ```
3. Replace those 4 files with the same 4 files downloaded from the above link.
4. Restart unity by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing `setsid unity` (or logging out and in again).
5. If you don't like it then just replace the icons with the backed up icons and restart unity.

Example:

[image: Launcher with no borders around icons]

Comment: In 12.04, a bit of this has changed.  The folder for the icons is now /usr/share/unity/5/ (as Unity has changed versions for 12.04), and there is now one additional icon to replace: launcher_icon_shadow_62.png.  Using the method described above, one can simply copy any of the other blank icons to launcher_icon_shadow_62.png, so now there are five blank icons, and then use all five of them to replace the corresponding icons in /usr/share/unity/5/.

Comment: In 14.04 images are stored in /usr/share/unity/icons. All have svg format instead of png. Additionally replace launcher_icon_shadow_62.svg, to get rid of a shadow.

Comment: I cannot get replacement files in given link - may you update link URL please. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible, and rather simple.

1. Install compizconfig-settings-manager:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Then run `about:config` in the run dialogue in Unity: press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `about:config`.
3. CCSM will pop up with the Unity plug-in open. Navigate to the experimental tab:

   [image: ccsm. it is open.]
4. Now change the Backlight Mode to "Backlight Always Off".
5. Problem solved.

In light of your comment, the box never 100% goes away (by design).

#### Small note from @ccpizza concerning 16.04.1.

- > In ubuntu xenial 16.04.1 the Experimental tab is gone, and the setting
  >   is now under the Launcher tab and the dropdown is called Launcher Icon
  >   Backlight Mode.

Comment: This should be the selected answer. Thanks a ton @RolandiXor

Comment: In ubuntu xenial 16.04.1 the *Experimental* tab is gone, and the setting is now under the *Launcher* tab and the dropdown is called ***Launcher Icon Backlight Mode***.

Answer (score 4):

I scripted the removal of the boxes around the applications and the one around the Ubuntu button (for 12.04):

```
cd /usr/share/unity/5
wget -O transparent54.png "https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiFpK.png"
wget -O transparent62.png "https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NvP0.png"

for name in squircle_shine squircle_edge squircle_base squircle_base_selected launcher_icon_back launcher_icon_edge launcher_icon_shine
do 
    sudo mv ${name}_54.png ${name}_54.ori.png \
        && sudo ln -s transparent54.png ${name}_54.png
done

for name in squircle_shadow launcher_icon_glow launcher_icon_shadow
do 
    sudo mv ${name}_62.png ${name}_62.ori.png \
        && sudo ln -s transparent62.png ${name}_62.png
done
```

Then to restart Unity, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `setsid unity`. The result looks much cleaner to me.

Before:

[image: with boxes]

After:

[image: without boxes]

To switch back:

```
cd /usr/share/unity/5
for name in squircle_shine squircle_edge squircle_base squircle_base_selected launcher_icon_back launcher_icon_edge launcher_icon_shine
do 
    sudo rm ${name}_54.png \
        && sudo mv ${name}_54.ori.png ${name}_54.png
done

for name in squircle_shadow launcher_icon_glow launcher_icon_shadow
do 
    sudo rm ${name}_62.png \
        && sudo mv ${name}_62.ori.png ${name}_62.png
done
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this locally, we don't have to modify the files in the folder /usr/share/unity/. Instead we can just copy these files in the gtk theme folder under a folder "unity" that you create. This will override the files in /usr/share/unity/ and also, this way, a system update will not remove the change.
But I have a different question. After removing the border, it looks like there is too much space between the icons and also between the icons and the border of the launcher. Is there a way to reduce the spacing inbetween?